# Formula to find solution for whole numbers

Tags: combinatorics

> If $A,B$ are whole numbers (0, 1, 2, 3...) how many solutions will you have for
>   $$A+B=5$$
>   up to swapping the variables?

I know that these are the outcomes, and I see a pattern forming:
$$0 + 5 = 5$$
$$1 + 4 = 5$$
$$2 + 3 = 5$$
But how do I find a formula that works for
$$A+B = k$$
where $k$ is *any* whole number?

Comment: Let's say A is smaller or equal to B, then we know that A is smaller or equal $\frac K 2 $ but for any natural number n less or equal to $\frac K 2$ we have that $n+ (K-n) =K$. And those are thus all the solutions.

Comment: Are you considering ordered pairs or unordered pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Using the Stars and Bars method you have $1$ bar and $k$ stars. Hence the number you are looking for is:

$\lceil\frac{1}{2}\cdot\binom{k-1}{2-1}\rceil+1=\lceil\frac{1}{2}(k-1)\rceil+1$

where $1/2$ is tu count up to swapping variables and the $1$ stands for the unique pair $(0,k)$ (up to swapping as you say of course).

Comment: Just wanted to note that your expression simplifies to ⌈(k+1)/2⌉

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
&0\to0+0\\
&1\to0+1\\
&2\to2+0,1+1\\
&3\to3+0,2+1\\
&4\to4+0,3+1,2+2\\
&5\to5+0,4+1,3+2\\
&6\to6+0,5+1,4+2,3+3\\
&7\to7+0,6+1,5+2,4+3\\
&\cdots\end{align}$$

Is it so difficult to see the pattern ?

Comment: I see the partern, Im looking for the formula if it asks A+B=k

Comment: @TonyConte: it's in front of your eyes, so what are you missing ?